# RemoteServerValidationCallback Exception When Connecting to Google Cloud SQL from App Engine using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I recently upgrade the Entity Framework Nuget packages in my solution to version 7.0.0 and I am now getting a RemoteCertificateValidationCallback exception.  The exception message states, "The remote certificate was rejected..."  This was not happening when I was running version 6.0.1.  My solution is running in Google's App Engine and is connecting to Google's Cloud SQL server.  The connection string I use looks like:

```
"ConfigurationContext": "Server=10.123.456.789;Database=development;User Id=myuser;Password=mysecretpassword;TrustServerCertificate=True"
```

As can be seen above, I tried setting the TrustServerCertificate option in the connection string to True and I also tried enabling "Allow only SSL connections" in the Google Cloud SQL server but I am still getting the above error.  I believe I could override the RemoveCertificateValidationCallback method in my code and always return True to avoid this issue but it is not secure and I would like to avoid that if possible.  Any ideas as to how I should proceed?  Thanks!

Comment: While the Microsoft documentation says that connection string keywords are not case-sensitive they don't say anything about the values. Have you tried `TrustServerCertificate=true` instead of `TrustServerCertificate=True`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately, that did not fix the issue.